# No subresource locator found for path /

Tags: rest, cxf

I am writing a simple cxf configured restful service. But I keep getting this error "No subresource locator found for path /" for a particular method. While this method is correctly mapped the url and able to get the parameter, but however, always throw this error and return 404.

Answer (score 17):

You might have forgotten to specify request type at the rest call, Check you have put proper annotations like @Get, @Post.. in your call or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to share your complete code for better answer.

Verify all these elements are declared properly like below:

```
package com.test.rs.sample;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.test.rs.dto.Student;

@Path("/student")
@Provider
public interface StudentService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Student getStudent(@PathParam("id")Long id);

    @GET
    @Path("/getAll/")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Student getAllStudents();

    @POST
    @Path("/add/")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response addStudent(Student student);

    @PUT
    @Path("/update/")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response updateStudent(Student student);

    @DELETE
    @Path("delete/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Student deleteStudent(@PathParam("id")Long id);
}
```